# INSTALL_REFERRER not received before application launched

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I want to catch INSTALL_REFERRER intent at my own receiver.
I implemented receiver

```
public class InstallReferrerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           Log.d("Broadcast", "RECEIVED!");
        }
}
```

and add at Manifest

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receiver.InstallReferrerReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When i want to test receiver, i install my application(not launch) and send broadcast via adb

```
am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER --es "referrer" "utm_medium=partner&utm_campaign=partner_name"
```

But can't see any logs. After lounch, it work correct and receive intents.

From "Testing Google Play Campaign Measurement"

> To broadcast the INSTALL_REFERRER intent to your application:
>
> 1. Verify that your application is not currently running.
> 2. Open a terminal and run this command: ...

But my receiver not receive intents, before i launch application first time. Is this a correct behavior? When i receive this intent if i install application from market with referrer params?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Android 3.1+ application's BroadcastReceiver (or any other component) will not be fired until user has launched the application at least once. Until then it is in the "stopped" state

That [is an intended behaviour](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html) and prevents some security risks.

Comment: I can't believe that. Wouldn't that render the "INSTALL_REFERRER" completely useless? The broadcast is always fired on install before the first launch so it can never be received?!

Comment: What do you mean by that ? What is the behaviour of this broadcast? The _fact that broadcast is fired_  is unrelated to _fact that it is not received_. It might be a sticky broadcast received immediately after process launch explicitly initiated by user

Answer (score 2):

you must set flag `Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES` when send `broadcastintent`.

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("referrer", referrer);
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER");
intent.putExtras(extras);
intent.setPackage(packageChanged);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You adb command is not complete. Try with this one:

```
./adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n <your package>/<your package>.receiver.InstallReferrerReceiver --es "referrer" "utm_medium%3Dpartner%26utm_campaign%3Dpartner_name"
```

Note: the referrer should be url encoded.

Comment: Adb command correct, it works after first application launch.
The answer at platform restrictions, as answered by Drew -
application's BroadcastReceiver (or any other component) will not be fired until user has launched the application at least once